# last row value gets selected in all rows select tag

Tags: php, jquery, each

Here when i load the page there are multiple rows where each row contain an select tag with multiple option values and my problem is all rows select tag is getting selected the last loop value. for example if i have 3 and 4 as the select tag values for 1 and 2 rows respectively but an both rows last value 4 is getting selected.

here is my code

```
            $.each(detail_info, function (key, value) {

            var opts = "";
            $.each(users, function (key1, data) {

                var selected = "";
                if (data['id'] == value['created_by']) selected = "selected";
                opts += "<option " + selected + " value='" + data['id'] + "'>" + data['real_name'] + "</option>";
            });


            tbody_html += "<tr class='child' data-detail_id='" + value.id + "'>";
            tbody_html += "<td>" + cnt + "</td>";
            tbody_html += "<td>" + value.stock_id + "</td>";
            tbody_html += "<td>" + value.description + "</td>";
            tbody_html += "<td><input type='text' class='tid_transaction_id form-control' value='" + value.transaction_id + "'></td>";
            tbody_html += "<td><input type='text' class='tid_application_id form-control' value='" + value.application_id + "'></td>";
            tbody_html += "<td><input type='text' class='tid_ref_name form-control' value='" + value.ref_name + "'></td>";
            /*tbody_html += "<td> <select style='width: 180px !important;' class='form-control kt-select2 ap-select2 tid_user_id' name='tid_user_id' id='tid_user_id'><option value=''>select</option>"+ $.each(users,function(key1, value1){ option_html += "<option value='" + value1.id + "'>" + value1.real_name + "</option>" }) +"</select></td>";*/
            tbody_html += "<td><select style='width: 180px !important;' class='form-control kt-select2 ap-select2 tid_user_id' name='tid_user_id' id='tid_user_id" + cnt + "'><option value=''>select</option></select></td>";

            tbody_html += "</tr>";
            cnt++;


            $("#tid-items_tbody").html(tbody_html);
            $(".tid_user_id").append(opts);


        });

    });`
```

Comment: You would try with `$(".tid_user_id:last").append`

Comment: here only last row gets affected